# plot wavfile with python

Tags: python, wav

i would like to plot a wav file with python. This should show a sinus.

This is my code so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import wave
import sys


spf = wave.open("sin.wav", "r")

# Extract Raw Audio from Wav File
signal = spf.readframes(-1)
signal = np.fromstring(signal, np.int8)


# If Stereo
if spf.getnchannels() == 2:
    print("Just mono files")
    sys.exit(0)

plt.figure(1)
plt.title("Signal Wave...")
plt.plot(signal)
plt.show()
```

I got this Error: WAV header is invalid: nAvgBytesPerSec must equal product of nSamplesPerSec and nBlockAlign, but file has nSamplesPerSec = 16384, nBlockAlign = 1, and nAvgBytesPerSec = 44100

Does anyone know how to get this working ?

Comment: Are you sure that your audio file is ok? Just tested it here with a file and I don't get an error

Comment: `WAV header is invalid` is pretty straightforward. Try another WAV, or try opening your file in Audacity and saving it into (a valid) WAV